# How to filter these NSArray with NSPredicate?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

```
-(void) vUpdateHistoryAndSuggestionEntries
{
    NSArray * potentialHistory = [[self class] arHistory];
}
```

potentialHistory is an array of `NSString` objects.

I want to filter only elements that start with, for example, @"Cat" in case insensitive manner.For example,

if the NSArray contains

Cathy
Cat
Dog

Then I want an array that contains

Cathy
Cat

I think NSPredicate is ideal for this. Any other ways will be fine too.

There are similar questions. However, in those questions, NSArray contains dictionary. I want to filter based on the actual element of the array instead of element of element of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *yourArray;
NSPredicate *aPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] 'C'"];
NSArray *theFilteredArray = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:aPredicate];
```

**Hope this will help you.**

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to use NSPredicate:

```
NSArray *sampleArray = @[@"Cathy", @"Cat", @"Dog"];
NSArray *filteredSampleArray = [sampleArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains[c] %@",@"ca"]];
NSLog(@"%@",filteredSampleArray);
```

This will output:

(
    Cathy,
    Cat
)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *filterStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name LIKE[c] '*%1$@*'",searchStr];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:filterStr];
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [yourArrayofNames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

//here name is your property and yourArrayofNames is your array of objects.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need `NSPredicate` for simply this.

```
for (NSString* item in arHistory){

    if ([item rangeOfString:@"cat" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == 0){//occurs at beginning

        [potentialHistory addObject:item];
    }
}
```

EDIT: If potentialHistory is immutable, use another array to store these and `init` potentialHistory with it.

```
NSArray* potentialArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray*)array]
```

Comment: True, you don't need a `NSPredicate`. But it's bad practice.

Comment: I see. Any specific reasons for that?